# How to add favicon on newly created web page through notepad?

Tags: html, favicon

I have made a webpage through notepad. And want to have a "faveicon" but can't add it. 
Here's my html's head part:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
```

after title part i typed this in head.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the favicon directly from your browser? I.e. `http://yourdomain/favicon.ico`.

Comment: What are those quotes you just edited in?

Comment: Try removing the double-quotes around the declaration and also try removing the leading '/' character from the `href` attribute. You could also use a tool like `firebug` to see if the browser even tries to load the icon.

Comment: "" double quotes were not actually written in my code. Here while asking question my code wasn't visible that's why i wrote it in double quote!

Comment: If anyone finds it useful then please vote this up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By putting the image in the same folder where my web page was located and writing this code it worked :)

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="h.ico">
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following in your `HEAD` section, remember to change `type` and `href`:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/myicon.png">
```

Comment: Try to force-refresh your site (`Ctrl+F5` / `Ctrl+R`), it happens to me that browser sometimes "ignores" changes on favicons

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me..

```
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/specialicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

[Just check this url.. it will helpful to you..](http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/quick-tip-adding-a-favicon-to-your-website/)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a 16x16 png and then use

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.png" type="image/png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.example.com/favicon.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you place a favicon in the root folder of your website called "favicon.ico" then it will work!

Comment: Yes its in my root folder. But still can't see it!

Comment: Additionally, such icon files can be 16×16, 32×32, 48×48, or 64×64 pixels in size, and 8-bit, 24-bit, or 32-bit in color depth.